# storing object names in array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to c++ and I was wondering if you could store object names in an array to access them later using a for loop. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
    array[] = { "Obj1", "Obj2", "Obj3" };
    int i;

    class Class {
        public:
            string name; // the name of the object
            int age; // the age of the object
    }

    int main() {
      Class Obj1;
      Class Obj2;
      Class Obj3;
        Obj1.name = "Judy";
        Obj1.age = 29;
        Obj2.name = "Mike";
        Obj2.age = 38;
        Obj3.name = "Dorothy";
        Obj3.age = 19;

        for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])); i++) {

            cout << array[i].name << endl;
            cout << array[i].age << endl;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't just store the name and access it like you want to, but you could store the object itself(or a pointer/reference to it)

Comment: The closest you could get in C++ is with a `std::map<std::string, Class>`

Comment: Yes, you can store object names as strings to use them later.  No, it won't work the way you've shown, and no it's 99.99% of the time a terrible idea and not the right way to do it.  Store a pointer instead.  Object names are things for our monkey brains to use while we are writing the code.  The compiler obliterates them because the program doesn't reference things using text and words like we do.  If you try to force a program to work like a monkey it will all turn out poorly.

Comment: Sidenote: `array`  and `i` are global variables. You should avoid using global variables as much as possible.

Comment: @litelite "as much as possible" is exaggerated. Overusing globals is bad, using globals when appropriate is just fine. Consider for example `std::cout`, it is a global. Would you really advise to avoid `std::cout` whenever possible?

Comment: http://thispointer.com/unordered_map-usage-tutorial-and-example/

Comment: @J... I completely agree with your point, but forcing programmers to work like monkeys will  turn out poorly as well ;)

Comment: @tobi303 I would advise against declaring your own globals if you can do without. `std::cout` is one of the case where it is OK. But right now he is using a global as an iterator for a loop.

Comment: @litelite I get your point, I just think that terms like "avoid when ever possible" or "xyz is evil" do more harm than good. Even declaring your own global can be fine sometimes. If you tell a beginner to never use them they will never understand when it is ok to use one and when not. ...omg i am going soo offtopic ;)

Comment: [Laugh while you can, Monkeyboy.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=345uegSj-zQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to do that in C++ is using a `std::map<std::string,Class>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Class {
    public:
        string name; // the name of the object
        int age; // the age of the object
};

int main() {
  std::map<std::string,Class> objrefMap {
      { "Obj1", Class() },
      { "Obj2", Class() } ,
      { "Obj3", Class() }
  };

  objrefMap["Obj1"].name = "Judy";
  objrefMap["Obj1"].age = 29;
  objrefMap["Obj2"].name = "Mike";
  objrefMap["Obj2"].age = 38;
  objrefMap["Obj3"].name = "Dorothy";
  objrefMap["Obj3"].age = 19;

  for(auto objitem : objrefMap) {
      cout << objitem.second.name << endl;
      cout << objitem.second.age << endl;
  }
}
```

See the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ffae135cf326713).

Comment: the only use case I can think of is to store some   arbitrary named values  that were read from human-readable file and  ought be written to similar file format, while not all of variables may be present. I saw implementation of this as kind of global setting storage for  an app. Qt library got similar mechanism inside their QSettings. For other uses  this is just too slow to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to edit your code to fit your need. However this isn't the most optimal solution and requires a lot of effort. You could instead use a map. Hopefully this was helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class {
public:
    string name; // the name of the object
    int age; // the age of the object
}; //don't forget the semicolon here.

int main()
{
    int nameCount = 0;
    int ageCount = 0;
    string nameArray[10];
    int ageArray[10];

    Class Obj1;
    Class Obj2;
    Class Obj3;

    nameArray[nameCount] = Obj1.name = "Judy"; nameCount++;
    ageArray[ageCount]  = Obj1.age = 29; ageCount++;
    nameArray[nameCount] = Obj2.name = "Mike"; nameCount++;
    ageArray[ageCount]  = Obj2.age = 38; ageCount++;
    nameArray[nameCount] = Obj3.name = "Dorothy"; nameCount++;
    ageArray[ageCount]  = Obj3.age = 19; ageCount++;

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < nameCount && j < ageCount; i++, j++)
    {
        cout << nameArray[i] << endl;
        cout << ageArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Judy
29
Mike
38
Dorothy
19
```